# Can you help me with this integral?

Tags: integration

I have this integral: $$\int_{0}^{\pi} d\theta \sin\theta\left[ \frac{P+H \cos^2\theta}{(B+C\cos^2\theta)^{1/2}}\right],  $$ where $P=A x^2+ab,C=6ad,H=3ad, B=Ax^2+2ab$ are Physical constants. If $\cos\theta=u$, I have: $$2\int_{0}^{1}du \frac{P+H u^2}{(B+Cu^2)^{1/2}}.$$ If $u^2=t$, I have:

$$\int_{0}^{1}dt(t)^{-1/2}(P+Ht)(B+Ct)^{-1/2}.$$

This integral is very similar to 3.197.3 integral of the Gradshteyn's book. Am I right?

Comment: $$\int_{0}^{1}dt(t)^{-1/2}(P+Ht)(B+Ct)^{-1/2}=P\int_{0}^{1}dt(t)^{-1/2}(B+Ct)^{-1/2}+H\int_{0}^{1}dt(t)^{1/2}(B+Ct)^{-1/2}$$

Comment: Thank you for your observation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, first of all, substitute $\text{u}:=\cos\left(\theta\right)$:

$$\mathscr{I}:=\int_0^\pi\sin\left(\theta\right)\cdot\frac{\text{h}\cdot\cos^2\left(\theta\right)+\text{p}}{\sqrt{\text{b}+\text{c}\cdot\cos^2\left(\theta\right)}}\space\text{d}\theta=\int_{-1}^1\frac{\text{h}\cdot\text{u}^2+\text{p}}{\sqrt{\text{b}+\text{c}\cdot\text{u}^2}}\space\text{d}\text{u}=$$
$$\frac{\text{h}}{\text{c}}\cdot\int_{-1}^1\sqrt{\text{b}+\text{c}\cdot\text{u}^2}\space\text{d}\text{u}+\left(\text{p}-\frac{\text{b}\cdot\text{h}}{\text{c}}\right)\cdot\int_{-1}^1\frac{1}{\sqrt{\text{b}+\text{c}\cdot\text{u}^2}}\space\text{d}\text{u}\tag1$$

Now, we need to use:

$$\int_{-1}^1\sqrt{\text{b}+\text{c}\cdot\text{u}^2}\space\text{d}\text{u}=\sqrt{\text{b}+\text{c}}+\frac{\text{b}}{2\cdot\sqrt{\text{c}}}\cdot\ln\left|\frac{\text{b}+2\cdot\text{c}+2\cdot\sqrt{\text{c}}\cdot\sqrt{\text{b}+\text{c}}}{\text{b}}\right|\tag2$$

And:

$$\int_{-1}^1\frac{1}{\sqrt{\text{b}+\text{c}\cdot\text{u}^2}}\space\text{d}\text{u}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{\text{c}}}\cdot\ln\left|\frac{\text{b}+2\cdot\text{c}+2\cdot\sqrt{\text{c}}\cdot\sqrt{\text{b}+\text{c}}}{\text{b}}\right|\tag3$$

So, we end up with:

$$\mathscr{I}=-\frac{\left(\text{b}\cdot\text{h}-2\cdot\text{c}\cdot\text{p}\right)\cdot\ln\left|\frac{\text{b}+2\cdot\text{c}+2\cdot\sqrt{\text{c}}\cdot\sqrt{\text{b}+\text{c}}}{\text{b}}\right|-2\cdot\text{h}\cdot\sqrt{\text{c}}\cdot\sqrt{\text{b}+\text{c}}}{2\cdot\text{c}^\frac{3}{2}}\tag4$$

Comment: If $u=\cos\theta$, $\int_{0}^{\pi}\rightarrow \int_{1}^{-1}$. Am I right?

Comment: $P=\frac{\hbar^2 r^2}{2M}+gn_0(1-\epsilon)$, $h=3gn_0 \epsilon$, $b=\frac{\hbar^2 r^2}{2M}+2gn_0(1-\epsilon)$ and $c=6gn_0 \epsilon$. Where $r$ is the polar coordinate, $M$ is the mass and $g,\epsilon$ are constants. Now, I will integrate the variable $r$

Comment: Do you have any tips to evaluate this integral?

Comment: No, but I know I can do this.

Comment: @user3321 Can you tell me what the constants are, the value and that it physically represents because I think that there is something wrong?

Comment: Look, when I assume that $h$ is planks constant divided by $2\pi$, $\text{M}$ is the mass of the earth, $\text{g}=9.8$ and $\epsilon$ is the eccentricity of the orbit of the Earth. I got for the total integral that you posted in your comment: $\approx1.29081\times10^{37}$

Comment: $g\neq9.8$. $g$ is a constant that is positive. The other constants are just constant, they should not interfere with the final result. My problem is quantum. This is really a boring integral. The certainty that I have is that these integrals are in the Gradshteyn's book.